# Placing 2x10 trusses on 2x6 wall frame?

Tags: framing, structural

I plan to build a barn style roof truss on a building with 2x6 frame (studs).  I assume the top plate will also be 2x6.  Can I place a gambrel (barn style) 2x10 truss on 2x6 top plate?  Of course I would want the inside part of 2x10 to be flushed with 2x6 internally.  Suggestions please?

Comment: Are these commercial trusses you're talking about? And can you clarify (maybe with a sketch) what you mean with the flush internally bit? (Sub question to go with that: are you planning an overhang?) What's the overall size of the building (noting direction of rafters)? And since I'm asking, why do you want a gambrel roof?

Comment: Btw, the first photo is a shed but the second photo is the type of roof I want to build for my new house using 2x10 trusses over 2x6 frame

Comment: Pics don’t link, maybe do over?

Comment: Still 404. Try checking your link on a different device.

Comment: Since pics aren’t working, I’ll give the briefest possible summary. Gambrel trusses are usually engineered so they don’t fall down. Flush to the plate implies no knee wall supporting the elbow, which is extra hard. Just my opinion, but a gambrel roof (especially handmade) is a pain in the butt for no appreciable benefit.

Comment: Honestly, homemade trusses on anything larger than a shed sounds like a disaster to me. If you really want it, find a sympathetic engineer and they'll help you build something that won't fall down.